# JAXB: Namespace missing

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb

I am trying to serialize an XML from a class generated via JAXB.

The class:

```
package ws.avail;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "pos",
    "uniqueID",
    "availStatusMessages"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "OTA_HotelAvailNotifRQ")
public class OTAHotelAvailNotifRQ {
 ...
}
```

File "package-info.java":

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package ws.avail;
```

The marshaller (simplified without error handling):

```
context = JAXBContext.newInstance(rootElement.getClass());
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal(rootElement, stringWriter);
return stringWriter.toString();
```

This code generates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>  
<OTA_HotelAvailNotifRQ Version="1.000" Target="TEST">  
....
```

I expect something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<OTA_HotelAvailNotifRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" Version="1.000" Target="TEST">  
....
```

I have a similar code and works correctly, but I am unable to see why this code doesn't display the namespace. Any clue? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**YOUR MAPPINGS ARE CORRECT**

I tried out your model and it works for me:

**Demo**

```
package ws.avail;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        OTAHotelAvailNotifRQ rootElement = new OTAHotelAvailNotifRQ();
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(rootElement.getClass());
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(rootElement, stringWriter);
        System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><OTA_HotelAvailNotifRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"/>
```

---

**SOLUTION**

Usually when this problem occurs the `package-info` class was not compiled or not packaged with the application.

---

**FOR MORE INFORMATION**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html